# Meteor + Iron Router: Render after pageRender

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router

I have been playing around with Meteor lately and i am loving it, but 5 minutes into a project i am having a problem with rendering templates after calling {{ pageRender }} (Taking note that specifically {{>renderPage }} only render what Iron Router was told to render and ignores any other calls.)

The current code below works perfectly fine since it is still basic configuration, but the footer template is getting called "before" the dynamic page is rendered, which is resulting in the footer appearing above all page content. I have also tried to move the footer text into the main.html fine but the footer is still rendered before the {{ renderPage }} content.

**Iron Router Js:**

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
    //data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }
  });
});
```

**HTML source:**

```
<head>
  <title>NDA Site</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Render Navigation -->
    {{> navigation }}

    <!-- Render Page (Anything gets closed before render is called canceling grid out. Grid has been moved to each template for accuracy)-->
    <div class="renderPage-wrapper">{{ renderPage }}</div>

    <!--{{> footer }} 
    footer will not render after renderPage. Footer has been added to main.html as show below-->


        <div class="container"><div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p>YourSite &copy; {{year}}. All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
                <p>Powered by: NDA Site 0.1.2</p>
            </div>

            </div></div>

</body>
```

**Template source:**

```
<template name="footer">


        <div class="container"><div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p>YourSite &copy; {{year}}. All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
                <p>Powered by: NDA Site 0.1.2</p>
            </div>

            </div></div>
</template>
```

Any ideas of a work around? Or an explanation of why the render hierarchy is being ignored after the client runs {{ renderPage }}?

Sincerely,
Willie (Doc) W.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your syntax is completely wrong, you should not add bootstrap to project explicitly , instead run `meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3` and delete them from head.

Instead of script tags in footer create footer.js and in it make

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.footer.helpers({
       year: function(){
          return new Date().getFullYear();
       }
}
```

And if you want everything to be under each other, wrap {{renderPage}} into some div which will hold place for it until template is loaded.

Also, do you have Home template? Because that's what you are calling in iron-router

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. First and for most, i was currently using "meteor add bootstrap" which package was broke and creating some weird outputs which is why i temporary used the CDN instead, but after testing "mizzao:bootstrap-3" as you suggested bootstrap is now working correctly without the CDN's. As far as having the script tag that was just for inline testing, but not i can see why it did not work, thanks.

Comment: And finally when it comes to wrapping the {{renderPage}}, i have already tried wrapping it with multiple divs, containers, spans, and sections, but the problem that i am having is the container is automatically being closed before the {{renderPage}} can be called for some reason. Example: {{> navigation }}
    <div class="renderPage-wrapper">{{ renderPage }}</div>
    {{>footer }}   ; results in the .renderPage-wrapper to be empty, and the footer wrapper still getting called before the {{renderPage}}. Yes i do have a Home template.

Comment: ADd some css to it, e.g. min-width:100px or sth

Comment: Styling is working correct, it is just the div is still being closed before the page is called.

Comment: Ok, so how does your renderPage look? If it is dynamic template maybe try https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/

Comment: Dynamic rendering is the aim for this project. Just need the hierarchy to be in order. I will give this a try, and also Iron Router's yield template method. Then report back results.

Comment: Update: I am currently using the workaround of adding header and footer into my templates instead of having meteor/client/main.html host {{>navigation }} and {{>footer }}, which may actually be better for the particular project i am working on. But I will report back once i figure out why the HTML on the main.html div tags automatically close once the server looks for the {{ renderPage }}. Its basically just throwing {{ renderPage }} to the bottom of <body></body> no matter what

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured out a solution, which at the same time was me using Iron:router wrong(missing a step).

First a layout template needs to be defined.

```
<template name="layout">

  <div id="main-wrapper">

    {{>navigation }}


    <div class="container-fluid content">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 pull-right">
                {{>yield}}
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 pull-left">
                {{>sidebar}}
            </div>

    </div>
</div>

    <!--{{>footer }} // Normally you would render your footer here at the bottom of the page. Since the project i am working on consist of a static sidebar i moved the {{>footer}} to {{>sidebar}} -->

  </div><!-- Particle JS -->


  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.js"></script>
  <script src="http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>-->

</template>
```

Then a layout configuration needs to be set.

```
// Configure Iron:Router
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

The main.html or yourProject.html which has your head and body should look something like this.

```
<head>
  <title>Foobar</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://www.aperturestudiosmedia.com/favicon.ico">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Render Krater -->
</body>
```